# Ошибка java.net.SocketException: Too many open files при деплойменте в jboss-portal-2.7.2

Tags: jboss, java-ee

При запуске jboss-portal-2.7.2 с какого-то момента в логах начинает появляться сообщение:

```
2013-01-30 20:32:02,541 ERROR [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint] Socket accept failed
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:61)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

В папке deploy всего около 20 .war модулей. Как решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если запускаете под Linux, то увеличьте [ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html):

```
ulimit -n 10000
```